# Using subproperties in a list of superclass c#

Tags: c#

My scenario is this: I have an abstract superclass, let's call this SuperClass and some subclasses of this superclass, SubClass1,2,3.. I have a list of SuperClass and in this last i added some subclasses.

I wish to find objects with certain properties which are SPECIFIC to a given subclass.

for example:

```
public abstract class SuperClass{
public string name;
public int value}
public class SubClass1: SuperClass{
public double speed;}

list<SuperClass> list = new list<SuperClass>();
```

So from here i'd like to add subclasses (with different properties) and select these different properties dynamically (for example some client predicate if possible)

Answer (score 2):

Try using linq:

```
var items = list.OfType<TheSubClassTypeWithTheProperty>()
                .Where(x => x.Property == value);
```

Comment: I like this method.. Now suppose two subclasses have the same property.. Weight, I wish to find those with a certain weight, now what should i do different?

Also thanks to the below answer

Comment: @user1363200 - if these two classes implemented a common interface exposing this property you could use it in OfType<TheCommonInterface>, otherwise you would need to do the linq statement separately for each of the classes